# Pairwise similarity criterion in torch

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch, loss

I want to implement a new Criterion in torch7.

Basically, I have pair of samples for which I have a normalised similarity real value (let's denote it 'd').

Among existing Criterion, the closest I can have is the [CosineEmbeddingCriterion](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/criterion.md#nn.CosineEmbeddingCriterion) which provides the following loss :

```
             ⎧ 1 - cos(x1, x2),              if y ==  1
loss(x, y) = ⎨
             ⎩ max(0, cos(x1, x2) - margin), if y == -1
```

Obviously this is designed for pairs, but this is for classification problems.

In my problem, I want to implement a Criterion that provide the following loss function : 
 `loss(x1, y2, d) = | d - cos(x1,x2) |`

Unfortunately, unlike [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648796/add-my-custom-loss-function-to-torch), it does not appear to me that I cannot simply combine existing criterion to do that.

So I plan to go on the painful way to create a new module from [torch7 source file.](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/CosineEmbeddingCriterion.lua)

My questions are as follows :

- Am I correct that I don't any other straightforward solutions ?
- If I implement my own Criterion in torch7 :

  - is there a skeleton to write criterion or a guide ?
  - how can I check that it is valid ? (how to unit test it ?)

(it seems to me very easy to write a criterion that seems correct to me -- but not in practise)

Thank you in advance for any clue !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to write the `updateOutput` and `updateGradInput` functions for your criterion. Then, you can use it like any other criterion. Here is a skeleton.

https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/BCECriterion.lua

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured out. One may also want to provide a batch implementation of his/her criterion.