# How can I customize the loss function in Torch?

Tags: torch

I'm currently using Torch 7 and I need to customize the loss function in particular the Cross-Entropy error function.

I'm thinking of adding some parameters to Cross Entropy error function and I couldn't find which part should I modify.

I took a look at CrossEntropyCriterion.lua but still don't know the way cause I don't see any equation in this file.

Can anyone tell me where the equation is? or which file I should modify?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add my custom loss function to torch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648796/add-my-custom-loss-function-to-torch)

Answer (score 0):

in order to customize a loss function you have to change the methods `__init`, `updateOutput` and `updateGradInput`.

- `__init` is the class initialization function
- `updateOutput` will be called when you use `:forward()` method in your criterion
- `updateGradInput` will be called when you use `:backward()` and it is the gradient of your criterion

The structure of the customized criterion looks like:

```
local yourCriterion, parent = torch.class('nn.yourCriterion', 'nn.Criterion')

function yourCriterion:__init(your_parameters):
  parent.__init(self)
  ... (you can add as many parameters as you want to your criterion
       and give them the name your prefer)
  self.parameters = your_parameters


function yourCriterion:updateOutput(input)
  ... (your criterion code here)
  return value_of_the_criterion

function yourCriterion:updateGradInput(input):
  ... (your criterion gradient code here)
  return gradient
```

[EDIT]: You can find the code of the cross-entropy criterion here https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/CrossEntropyCriterion.lua

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the link to the cross-entropy criterion. I have edited my answer to add it.